# Como visualizar as versões do python que tenho no windows?

Tags: python

Estou com mais de uma versão do Python instalada no windows, 3.8 e 3.9, mas não sei como visualizar o diretório da versão 3.8 para deletar a pasta, ela não aparece, aparece somente a  pasta da 3.9, sendo que qdo rodo o python --version no terminal, aparece a versão 3.8.8... alguém pode me ajudar a "enxergá-la" e deletar?
Meu VS Code está dando problemas por causa disso, sempre que tento importar bibliotecas, fui orientada a deletar uma (a mais antiga) e ficar com a mais recente...

Answer (score -2):

No VS Code, do lado inferior esquerdo deve aparecer algo como "Python 3.x.x 64bit" clique em cima, em seguida irá aparecer na tela uma janela escrito "Selecionar interpretador", então você poderá escolher qual das versões instaladas quer utilizar.
Pelo que eu testei aqui, a versão que está de fato sendo utilizada é a que aparece do lado inferior esquerdo, e não a mostrada quando se dá o comando "python --version"